# Failover Cluster waits till the Site to Site DNS Replication done

Tags: active-directory, failover, failovercluster, file-server, file-replication-services

I created a failover cluster with 2 subnets in AWS VPC.

> In one subnet I have DC1 (10.30.10.101) and Node 01 (10.30.10.102).
>
> In other subnet, I have DC2 (10.30.12.101)and Node 02 (10.30.12.102).
>
> Cluster is created (10.30.10.120 and 10.30.12.120)
>
> I also created a file server role. (10.30.10.121 and 10.30.12.121)

So now, a remote computer can access the files in that shared folders. But the problem is, whenever I shutdown the active node, it waits until the "site to site replication" happns and changes the DNS records from failed note to secondary node (Node 1 to Node 2). I set the minimum replication time (15 mins) but I need the failover to be happened instantly. Manual replication also takes little time and its not practical. Whenever the cluster DNS and fileserver role DNS changes to the new active node IP, then again the shared folder can be accessed.

Could someone please tell me how to make that fully autamated straightaway?

Comment: Do you have a witness?

Comment: yes. one of the virtual disks in iscsi sever is acting as a Disk Witness.

Comment: Check that the witness is actually functioning when you do the shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable change notification in Active Directory to get DNS changes to propagate faster:

1. Open "Active Directory Sites and Services" MMC.
2. Go to Sites -> Inter-Site Transports -> IP
3. For each of the Sites in the list:

   1. Right-click and pick Properties.
   2. Switch to the "Attribute Editor" tab.
   3. Find the current value of "options" and set bit 1 to on. For example, if the value is currently 4, that means bit 3 is on, 100 in binary. So turning on bit 1 gives us 101, which is a decimal 5. So the new "options" value should be 5.
   4. Click OK.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry it took long to reply. So do we have to edit this on each site? Because, Sites -> Inter-Site Transports -> IP has only one entry which is "DEFAULTSITELINK". By default it was was <not set>. So I changed it to one. But when I go to each site > servers > server name > NTDS settings > automatic generated entry. It has 1 or 5 or 13 in each site. SO i didnt change it. But still the replication takes 15 mins for replication.